# How to insert html table row when checkbox is clicked in codeigniter

Tags: php

How can I solve this? I am new to this codigniter so can anyone explain to this how to solve this

```
 <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>Quiz/add_assign_stu">
                    <input type="hidden" name="teach_id" value="<?php echo $teach_id; ?>">
                    <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th></th>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>User Id</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>

                        <?php
                          foreach ($student as $stu) {
                        ?>

                        <tr>
                          <th>
                            <input class="form-group" type="checkbox" name="click[]" value="<?php echo $stu->users_id;?>">
                          </th>
                          <th><?php echo $stu->name; ?></th>
                          <td><?php echo $stu->users_id;?></td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php
                          }
                        ?>

                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

controller

```
public function add_assign_stu()
    { 
      $click = $this->input->post('click');

          $this->Common_model->insert_record('student_exam_list',$values);

      redirect("Quiz/importFile/");
    }
```

I have a HTML table with a checkbox in one of the columns. I want to know how I could get the row data when the user clicks on the checkbox with javascript (without jquery)? Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You have to prepare html in add_assign_stu() function and return this html response as ajax response. And after ajax success, append the html after last tr of table with jquery.